# Parse add extra property only offline

Tags: parse-platform, local-datastore

I have a PFObject subclass and I want to add a property, Example:

```
@NSManaged var saved: Bool
```

But I don't want it to sync to the cloud at all and I don't want to add it to my object model on the cloud. Is it possible? If yes, if I use `saveEventually()` with an object with this property set is it going to save properly to the cloud without the property or..?

Comment: did you figure it out?

Comment: I just added another online property unfortunately :(

Answer (score 0):

One way could be to use NSUserDefaults.

You could use the Parse Object ID and as the key, and the saved Bool as the value.

It would not be tied to your object model, but you need to have some link to it - hence the parse auto generated object id.

Comment: And I'm not accepting this cause I would need to filter objects based on that property